# How to pass data from nextjs layout to children

Tags: reactjs, layout, next.js, breeze

I have read almost all solutions regarding `createContext` and `useContext` methods. But all of them suggest create context inside `_app.js` file which is not relevant when you want to send `user` object down to components, because sometimes user is a guest and sometimes it is authenticated.

If I implement a `UserContext` and use it as a wrapper for `Component` like so:

```
const App = ({Component, pageProps}) => {
    const {user} = useAuth({middleware:'auth'})
    
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{user:user}}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default App
```

When user is not authenticated, it causes the app to refresh on `Login` page.

Here is my Layout:

```
const AppLayout = (props) => {
    const {user} = useAuth({middleware: 'auth'})

    return (
        <div className="min-h-screen">
            <Navigation user={user}/>

            {/* Page Heading */}
            <header className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow">
                <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400">
                    {props.header}
                </div>
            </header>

            {/* Page Content */}
            <main>
                {props.children}
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AppLayout
```

And this is my page:

```
const Index = () => {
    return (
        <AppLayout
            header={<h2 className="font-semibold text-xl leading-tight">
                Dashboard
            </h2>}>
        
            Hello dear {i_need_user_here}
       </AppLayout>)
}

export default Index
```

Comment: The user information is passed through context, you can simply call `const {user} = useAuth({middleware: 'auth'})` in your `Index` component to have access to it.

Comment: @juliomalves - I've used this method but unfortunately it doesn't work, because every time I use ```useAuth``` it sends a request to server and react renders the component before response. So as you may see, the user object is undefined.